# windows 7 taskbar preview mods

Tags: .net, windows, taskbar

Is there a way to access and change the preview offered by Windows 7, when you hover an application ? I mean changes like : size of the preview box, or some special content.
Can this be done using the .NET framework ?

Thanks!

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298556/ensure-wpf-taskbar-window-preview-is-actualized/6298664

Comment: Take a look at [this screencast](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/yochay/programming-the-windows-7-taskbar--custom-previews-and-thumbnail-clips) it's probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How To Geek [offers an app](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14442/increase-the-size-of-taskbar-preview-thumbnails-in-windows-7/) to help with thumbnail size. Or [you can do it in the registry](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/increase-taskbar-thumbnail-preview-size-windows-7/).

Custom thumbnails are handled by the answer CodeNaked linked.